# when adding crontab got No such file or directory in CentOS 7.7

Tags: linux, cron

I want to make a new repeatable action (my os is CetnOS 7.7), I have two files both located in `/home/user/` and have rights for execution

addmyscript:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0-59 * * * * /home/user/myscript
```

myscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
mess="test cron"
echo "$mess"
```

But when I type in console `crontab /home/user/addmyscript`
I got this message in a file `/var/spool/mail/root`

```
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0>
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>

/bin/sh: /home/user/myscript
: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try run this script outside cron ? maybe it haven't execute attribute. let you show me output of command: ls -lh /home/user/myscript . notice, script is called with root EUID and EGID.

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 34 Mar 24 13:47 /home/user/myscript

If I just execute "bash myscript" it shows

myscript: line 2: $'\r': command not found
test cron

Its working, though it has an error (I guess because I created those files in Windows and copied to linux maching thru ssh client)
It can't be the issue... or it is?